# Is it possible to reset all Google Chrome extension settings?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Recently, all of my Google Chrome extensions have stopped working on all of my computers. I want to know if it's possible to reset all of the Chrome extension settings to the defaults (because I'm hoping that this will fix the problem.) Is it possible to reset all extension settings to the defaults?

Comment: I would try to re-install them, I'm not sure restoring their settings back to default would fix the problem.

Comment: In what way do they no longer work? It sounds more like a browser-wide problem than extension-specific.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, but it depends on how they store their settings—there are (too?) many.

## Cookies

If the extension stores its settings in a cookie, then you will need to find and delete the relevant cookies from `chrome://settings/cookies` (you can delete all cookies with `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData` if you don't use them in general).

## Local Storage

If the extension stores its settings in local-storage, then you will need to navigate to the *Local Storage* directory in your [UserData folder](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/user_data_dir.md#Mac-OS-X) and delete the relevant data. For example:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local Extension Settings
```

If you only want to reset some extensions, you can cross-reference the folder names with the extension(s) in question by selecting the *Developer mode* option in the `chrome://extensions` to see the GUID (e.g., `mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja` = Google Dictionary, so delete `mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja` folder)

## Databases

Extensions can also store their data in the `IndexedDB` directory:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/IndexedDB
```

Extension databases are prefixed with `chrome-extension_`.Again, delete the relevant folder(s).

## Post-reset

Finally, restart Chrome and the extension(s) should be reset to their default settings. Depending on the extension(s), they may or may not pop up their configuration page and ask you to configure them for the "first time".